# Get the last changed date of a xml-file with vb.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Is it possible to geht the date, when a xml-file last time was changed. I mean the date, which you can see, if you right-click the file and click properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
File.GetLastWriteTime("c:\xmlFile.xml")
```

[File.GetLastWriteTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)

> Returns the date and time the
>   specified file or directory was last
>   written to.